# How do I have subsite inherent top link bar from child of parent site, SP2010

Tags: master-page, sub-site, inheritance, top-link-bar, site-settings

I am trying to replicate the top link bar from a subsite of the parent site down to its own subsites, however, the subsites keep pulling the top link bar from the parent. Example:

.com/Parent/

.com/Topsite/Child

.com/Topsite/Child/subsite1

.com/Topsite/Child/subsite2

.com/Topsite/Child/subsite3

In the above, the Child site has "Display the navigation items below the current site" and the subsites have "Display the same navigation items as the parent site" yet the subsites and below will bypass the Child site and use the top link bar from the Topsite.

How do I have the subsites use the second level top link bar?